# Catch "FileNotFoundException"

Tags: c#

I have a method to get the folder path of a particular file:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
               Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "file.txt");
```

And later, I use this to read the text in the file:

```
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(filePath); // "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\file.txt"
        string myString = rdr.ReadToEnd();
```

Trouble is, if the file doesn't exist, it throws a `FileNotFoundException` (obviously). I want to hopefully use an `if/else` to catch the error, in which the user can browse to find the file directly, but I'm not sure what to use to verify if `filePath` is valid or not.

For example, I can't use:

```
if (filePath == null)
```

because the top method to retrieve the string will always return a value, whether or not it is valid. How can I solve this?

Comment: `if(!File.Exists(filePath))`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: what happens when the file was deleted between Exists() returned true and file access attempt was made?

Comment: Why don't you also **catch the exception** and allow the user then to select a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx):-

```
if(File.Exists(filePath))
{
  //Do something
}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

While `File.Exists()` is appropriate as a start, please note that ignoring the exception can still lead to an error condition if the file becomes inaccessible (dropped network drive, file opened by another program, deleted, etc.) in the time between the call to `File.Exists()` and `new StreamReader()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
               Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "file.txt");

if(!File.Exists(filePath))
{
/* browse your file */
}
else
{

        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(filePath); // "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\file.txt"
        string myString = rdr.ReadToEnd();
}
```